# .htaccess file is not working properly on Godaddy server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cgi, hosting

I have hosted my folder on godaddy linux cpanel. Wordpress files are in inside /public_html/tma.

I am facing strange issue that my .htaccess file is not working properly.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I request for this wordpress folder, http://{myip}/{uniquestring}/tma/ then even if it has index.php, it displays 404 error

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file? And is http://{myip}/{uniquestring}/tma/ the URL to public_html?

Comment: @Stevish this is url to tma folder inside public_html

Answer (score 0):

WordPress recommends this for if your files are in a subdirectory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No success


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?12.23.223.23/sdfssfsf/tma/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tma/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tma/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?12.23.223.23/sdfssfsf/tma/$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ tma/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: i replaced `my_subdir ` with `tma` and `example.com` with `12.23.223.23/sdfssfsf/tma/` but no luck

Comment: Where are your wordpress files? You're supposed to replace `my_subdir` whith whatever directory has the files. In your original question you said they were in /wordpress_project.

Comment: sorry if fixed my mistake. I replaced my_subdir with my directory name tma but still issue is there.

Comment: I moved my project public_html & kept .htaccess config as https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#mw-content-text

When i access any route which doesnt have .php its giving 404 error by cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding AllowOverride All in your .htaccess File.

Thanks.